# How can i increase my erc20 token price by web3 js?

Tags: ico, erc20

How can I increase my erc20 token price? when I see BNB token from Etherscan, there I can see the price but my token price shows $0. How can i increase price?

When in Binacne platform, BNB token Buy and Sell happens, then the rate show's in Ethereum.Now my questions is, when in my token, in my website, buy/sell happens, then how can i push this price rate in Ethereum by web3.js.